# Cannot create a list of files within a directory with boost

Tags: c++, file, boost, directory

I just copied the following code snippet from other question posted in Stackoverflow. And I wanted to know how to create a list of files within a directory that contains a common ending. I finished understanding how to set my project so it can include the library boost. 
However when running my code I get the following error message:

```
D:\CPP_Dev\Create_Virtual_Raster\Create_Virtual_Raster\create_list.cpp:26:66: error: 'ret' was not declared in this scope
if (fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext) ret.push_back(it->path().filename());
```

The code snippet I just run is this one:

I already set the library boost to be included in my code. 
I checked problems with semicolons and data type declarations.

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED 
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>


namespace fs = ::boost::filesystem;

// return the filenames of all files that have the specified extension
// in the specified directory and all subdirectories

string path = "D:/_TEST_MOSAICING_S1_TOOL/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180111T043843_20180111T043910_020102_02245A_1664";
string ext = ".tif";

void get_all(const fs::path& root, const string& ext, vector<fs::path>&   ret)
{
    if (!fs::exists(root) || !fs::is_directory(root)) return;

    fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root);
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit;

    while (it != endit)
    {
        if (fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext) ret.push_back(it->path().filename());
       ++it;

    }
}
```

I just expected a list of three files included in the directory.

Comment: `std::` is missing before vector, string etc.

Comment: rafix07 [is right](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KCEAdDVtrtfqXG8d).

Comment: It solved the problem! But still having an error message:

Comment: I mean, solved the first Error. But now I received: C:\Users\<myname>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFogf1c.o:create_list.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::path::extension() const'

Comment: @RogerAlmengor Now you have linker errors, you need to add these libraries `-lboost_system` and `-lboost_filesystem` as linker option to build your application.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will work on that. Hopefully it will compile.